Failed acces css and js when running local laravel project in mobile
I want to access my local laravel project on mobile. i have run php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 and i have successfully accessed the project on mobile. but when i open the project the css and js from the project seems not connected. i use tailwind css
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0

php artisan serve isn't a proper web server. It's meant to only be used for development purposes.
Tailwind is a compiled tool, my assumption is that without a proper web server to npm run prod, your tailwind classes aren't being compiled. Same with your JS, assuming you're using a bundling tools like Vite or Yarn.
